# How to specify variables in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to select every 6th row in the D column.  I thought I could do something like

```
= D(E1 * 6)
```

where E is a column that just lists integers 1, 2, 3,....
Excel does not accept this syntax.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "select?"  Do you actually want to select them, or perform an operation, like SUM, on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the INDIRECT function to build a cell reference out of a string.

```
=INDIRECT("D" & E1 * 6)
```